# Selenium add weekdays to a date, weekend days not calculated correctly

Tags: java, weekday, java.util.calendar, date

I am running the below code on `6/7/2018` in order to omit weekends from any dates returned. However the code seems to determine the below days as the weekend.

```
13/7/2018 - Friday & 14/7/2018 - Saturday
```

rather than

```
14/7/2018 - Saturday & 15/7/2018 - Sunday
```

I am updating the field indicated to increase / reduce the amount of days in the future I want to select.

If I input 5 days the date returned is `12/7/2018` and if I input 6 days the date returned is `15/7/2018`.

Is there something obvious I am missing, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Date date=new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
date=calendar.getTime(); 
SimpleDateFormat s;
s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

System.out.println(s.format(date));

int days = 5; //I am updating this value to increase and decrease days
for(int i=0;i<days;)
{
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    //here even sat and sun are added
    //but at the end it goes to the correct week day.
    //because i is only increased if it is week day

    if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)<=5)
    {
        i++;
    }

}
date=calendar.getTime(); 
s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(s.format(date));
```

Comment: I have been looking all over for the answer and currently cannot find what I'm looking for otherwise wouldn't have posted on here.  New to this and not worked with dates before so if you could point me in the right direction to the documentation that would be great thanks. Tried lots of different ways of updating the code based on the things I've ben reading but sadly not getting the desired results.

Comment: Why the downvotes, please? I find this question clear and useful. While the research effort may not be very clear to see, I believe it’s been made. The question is very clear about desired behaviour and how observed behaviour differs, and it presents an example that is about minimal and certainly both complete and verifiable. Most first Stack Overflow questions aren’t so good as this one.

Answer (score 4):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.UK);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Truk"));
    System.out.println(date.format(dateFormatter));
    int days = 5;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < days) {
        date = date.plusDays(1);
        DayOfWeek day = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (! day.equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) && ! day.equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(date.format(dateFormatter));
```

Output today (Sunday 8th July):

```
08/07/2018
13/07/2018
```

13th July is next Friday, so obviously it didn’t take Friday as weekend.

> Is there something obvious I am missing(?)

It don’t think it’s that obvious: The `Calendar` class numbers the days of the week from 1 for Sunday through 7 for Saturday. This comes from an American understanding of weeks. So when your condition was that the day of week should be less than or equal to 5, you included Sunday (1) through Thursday (5) and filtered out Friday (6) and Saturday.

> …if you could point me in the right direction to the documentation…

To find this information in the documentation you would have to look under each constant for day of week, `SUNDAY`, etc., and there follow the link Constant Field Values. See the links at the bottom of this answer.

The `Calendar` class has proved poorly designed (despite attempts to fix the problems with `Date`) and is now long outdated too. Instead I recommend that you use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Which I of course do in the snippet above.

One of many problems with `Calendar` is the use of `int` for day of week (and other items that have names rather than being numbers). It’s unnatural and very easy to confuse. One may say that you reinforced the problem by comparing to 5 rather than to `Calendar.FRIDAY`, but because of the American numbering the latter wouldn’t have solved your issue either. `java.time`’s `DayOfWeek` is an enum and doesn’t invite for comparing using “less than” or “is before” (though you may, and it would work in your case). The code referring to named constants `SATURDAY` and `SUNDAY` is not only clearer to read, it is also less error-prone.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- Documentation of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)
- [`Calendar.SUNDAY`documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY)
- [Constant Field Values documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY)

Comment: Thank you so much, will look into using this. Appreciate your help